# How can I get page id, wikidata id of some title along with multiple languages in a single API call?

Tags: api, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I have been trying to call Wikipedia API to retrieve page id and wikidata item id using below call and it works fine.

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageprops&ppprop=wikibase_item&redirects=1&format=xml&titles=Cat

but I need to retrieve the same information from other languages of my choice for example if I mention German and French languages in my call, it should look for their translation of word Cat and retrieve their page info. There is langlink property in Wikipedia API but somehow it doesn't work with query action along with pageprop.

So ideally, I want something like this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageprops&ppprop=wikibase_item&prop=langlinks&lllang=de&lllang=fr&titles=Cat

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Using `lllang` twice will just result in the second value overwriting the first one. You'll have to omit the paramter and then you get all the links:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageprops|langlinks&ppprop=wikibase_item&titles=Cat

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was trying to get langlink work with pageprop and & ppprop but apparently the both can't work together in a single API call. The link you provided above  says "Unrecognized parameter: ppprop."

Comment: Wasn't paying attention. Fixed now.